# About Godel and Anselm

Tags: goedel, ontological-argument

Was Godel's work on trying to make Anselm's Ontological Argument more 'feasible' with modal logic successful or has this work just been lost in the many abstract debates that confuse the issues?

Comment: What historical basis is there for a belief that Gödel was working to extend and or improve Anslem's work in particular or prove the existence of a god in general?

Comment: In 'Ontological arguments'; an entry by Graham Oppy in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. Also 'Kurt Godel's Ontological Argument' (http://www.ontology.co/ontological-proof-contemporary.htm). Christopher Small wrote 'Reflections on Godel's Ontological Argument.' Also Jordan Howard Sobel wrote about Godel's  proof in 'On Being and Saying'.

Comment: Did Godel find Anselm's arguments inspiring?

Comment: Can modal logic be used to justify an ontological argument?

Comment: Godel was a Lutheran and a genius at Logic so it is conceivable he would try to apply Logic to questions of religion , so was he successful or at giving Anselm's argument some sort of validation in terms of Modal Logic or was it incomplete?

Comment: Did Godel show there was 'something' in Anselm's Arguments ?

Comment: Is no one interested?

Comment: Because the genius Godel tried to analyse Anselm's arguments in a positive way ; is this disquieting to those who hold to the dogma of materialism or secularism?

Comment: On the Quora website some user said Godel's attempt to clarify Anselm's argument with modal logic  was wrong because it was circular , which I thought was strange since Godel would know well how not to be circular..

Answer (score 4):

Gödel's work was successful. See Christoph Benzmüller, Bruno Woltzenlogel Paleo: "Formalization, mechanization and automation of Gödel's proof of God's existence", arXiv (2013). Gödel's logical deduction has passed an automated proof checking procedure. An overview including the philosophical environment (Anselm) is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof).